# Balance data using different criteria

Tags: machine-learning, data

I have a dataset of audio and text files that I want to balance using different criteria to train a neural network. The text and matching audio file are grouped under one ID.

For each ID, I have a number of words and some metadata.

Let's say my data have three metadata/criteria that need to be *balanced* (well... kind of, I want to be able to **choose the percentage for some** criteria values) :

- The **name** of the speaker, each speaker should have approximately the **same number of words**.
- The status of the speaker (***active*** if the speaker is still in activity or ***inactive*** if not), where I want approximately **70 % active** speakers and **30 % inactive**.
- The gender of the speaker, where I want approximately **50 % male** and **50 % female**.

Example : ID12345 with 10,000 words. Metadata : John, male and active

If I balance one of the criteria, then another, I will surely unbalance the previously balanced one.
Moreover, if I balance using only one criterion at a time, I could throw away data that could be useful to the balance of the following criteria, which mean I will end up with less data that I could have had optimally.

**Is there an algorithm that could balance the data using all criteria with their percentage target, and maximise the number of words remaining ?**

I'm looking for a general algorithm, with a **variable number of criteria**.

EDIT : I use C++ and MongoDB (but I'll accept other languages/tools if it can help me, as well as algorithms).

Answer (score 0):

You would need to balance the data according to the joint distribution of all 3 features.

One simple option is to treat each feature as categorical (binning any continuous features), then map each combination of features to a single new feature:

```
doc_len_tokens  | status   | gender | level
----------------|----------|--------|------
1               | active   | male   | 1
1               | active   | female | 2
1               | inactive | male   | 3
1               | inactive | female | 4
2               | active   | male   | 5
2               | active   | female | 6
2               | inactive | male   | 7
2               | inactive | female | 8
... etc ...
```

You would then stratify on `level` when sampling.

Here is an example in SQL:

```
SELECT
    data.unique_id,
    data.doc_num_tokens,
    data.status,
    data.gender
FROM (
    SELECT
        data.unique_id,
        data.doc_num_tokens,
        data.status,
        data.gender,
        row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY
                data.doc_num_tokens,
                data.status,
                data.gender
            ORDER BY
                newid()
        ) AS row_num
    FROM
        my_data AS data
) AS data
WHERE
    row_num <= ${number of rows to sample}
```

Comment: Thanks, but there are some problems with this :
• It doesn't take into account the number of words. If John who is an active male have texts that are longer than others (for example), I'll get a lot more of words for the level corresponding to <John, active, male>.
• I can't select target percentages for each value of criteria. For example, I'll get 50 % active and 50 % inactive, but I want 70 % and 30 %.

Maybe I'm missing something, I'm not accustomed with Pandas. I'm using C++ and MongoDB.

Comment: @AdrianB. the `name_tokens_len` feature is meant to represent number of words. You stratify according to the `level` feature I constructed on the right side. It's just a number that corresponds to a unique combination of the other features.

Comment: @AdrianB. I converted it to a SQL example, which is more or less the same thing

Comment: Unfortunately, the possibility to choose a target percentage for some of the criteria values (like 70 % active and 30 % inactive) is something I need and that isn't compatible with your response.

Just by curiosity, how did you obtain _name_tokens_len_ from the number of docs ? I think I understood the rest of your idea, except this part.

Comment: @AdrianB. I thought you meant "same number of words in the speaker's name". I also misunderstood that you want a specific distribution of individuals within your sample. For that you can maybe use some kind of rejection sampling, although there is probably a more efficient scheme.

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't have used the word "balanced" for all criteria. Thanks anyway for you answer. I've modified my question.

Comment: I suspect there is a clean statistical solution to this. I'll try to think of something.